# Maximum LMDB value size

Tags: python, database, lmdb

Is there a maximum size of value that can be inserted into an LMDB database? I am trying to insert a 16GB file into an LMDB which is initialized to size 32GB and I obtain this error:

```
File "build_lmdb.py", line 90, in write_entry
    txn.put(key.encode('ascii'), value)
lmdb.BadValsizeError: mdb_put: MDB_BAD_VALSIZE: Unsupported size of key/DB name/data, or wrong DUPFIXED size
```

Is there any way around this, or any setup parameter that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to the `MDB_val` section of the [LMDB documentation](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__mdb.html#structMDB__val), the maximum size of a data item that can be entered into a database is `0xFFFF_FFFF` bytes (which is `2^32 - 1` or about 4GiB), so 16GB/32GB would be too big for a single data item.

(It looks like you're using the Python bindings, but since those are just bindings for the C APIs, whatever limitations apply to the C APIs should also be relevant).